# Array Pointer in PHP

Tags: php

I'm a bit confused about array pointers in PHP. 
The below code worked fine:

```
$ages = [1, 3, 5];
while($age = current($ages)) {
  echo $age . ", ";
  next($ages);
}
```

But I've no idea why the below code didn't print any thing out:

```
$ages = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $ages[] = $i;
}
while($age = current($ages)) {
  echo $age . ", ";
  next($ages);
}
```

I also tried to print with for loop, but in below code only the for loop printed, the while loop still didn't print.

```
$ages = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $ages[] = $i;
}
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  echo $ages[$i] . ", ";
}
while($age = current($ages)) {
  echo $age . ", ";
  next($ages);
}
```

I'm really not sure why it behaved like this, anyone could help me out?

Comment: It's generally better to avoid screwing around with array pointers. Just use `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check if the result of `current()` is different from the boolean `false` (means the cursor did not find the element), not just assign its value. As when the value is `0`, you get `while(0)`, which breaks the loop.

```
$ages = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $ages[] = $i;
}
while($age = current($ages) !== false) {
  echo $age . ", ";
  next($ages);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/61WoL

However, this will fail should any of the elements in the array have the value of boolean `false`. Its therefor not recommended to iterate over the array like this at all, you should  instead be using the proper tools, by using a `foreach` loop. This doesn't actually move the cursor, but you can "make" it move the cursor by calling `next()` for each iteration.

```
$ages = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $ages[] = $i;
}
foreach ($ages as $age) {
    echo current($ages).", ";
    next($ages);
}
```

If you're just looking to print the values, the best way would be either printing directly from the `foreach` loop, or by using `implode()`.

```
foreach ($ages as $age) {
    echo $age.", ";
}
```

or

```
echo impolode(",", $ages);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know to check with !== false

Answer (score 4):

> why it behaved like this

**Tl;dr:** Because of the first element of the newly created array is `0` and the assignment operator returns the value assigned to the variable, which causes the expression evaluated to `false`, hence the while-loop's body never run.

---

After running the for-loop, the received array would be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

At first, the invocation of `current($ages)` will return the first element of the newly created array which is `0`, then the assignment operator `=` will return the value assigned to the `$age` variable, which is `0`. Then, the code will be:

```
while(0) {
  echo $age . ", ";
  next($ages);
}
```

`0` is evaluated to false, that's why the loop's body will never be run. Hence no output to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, the syntax of your php code is wrong:

Replace Line 5  with
`while($age == current($ages)) {`

You used `=` which isn't for comparisons but `==` is.
Try doing that, then see.

**Also**, you could do it in a much simpler way:

```
foreach($ages as $age) {
  echo "$age, ";
}
```